# Using "BIGINT UNSIGNED" in Rails schema / Active Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails-application that needs to be able to save fingerprints of files in a mysql-database. These fingerprints are numbers that fill the complete range of a BIGINT and even need to extra space of UNSIGNED. I can't use a "VARCHAR" since a mathematic-operation needs to be performed on the database-side later on.

So I created my table-columns like so:

```
t.column :fingerprint, 'BIGINT UNSIGNED'
```

Works like charm.

But when running

```
rake db:reset
```

I always get a schema.rb that includes:

```
t.integer  "fingerprint", :limit => 8
```

Manually editing to "BIGINT UNSIGNED" works but is immediately replaced, when I run "rake db:reset" again.

Is there any way to make this persistent between resets?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. If you set the schema format of your application to :sql everything should work as expected.

Edit your `config/application.rb` and make the following change/addition:

`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`

You can find a more detailed explanation in the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps

Comment: Hi I wondered if anyone had tried this. I attempted to enter this configuration item but I still get a schema.rb which has limit => 8. I cannot seem to fin any other way of getting my migrations to provide me with a larger signed integer column type?

Comment: Your old schema.rb will still be present in your project, but you should also have a schema.sql after that, which Rails will use.